# Cocoa: Implement Menu like functionality displayed inside window controller view or as a part of content view

Tags: macos, cocoa, menuitem

[image]

Want to implement view like this, on click of item another view appears or perform some action. kind of menu but inside content view.

Comment: well the system has NSPopupButton, which is a menu from a button ... will that not work?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [**WWDC TreeView sample**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TreeView/Introduction/Intro.html) -
it comes pretty close, at the very least it should provide a good starting point!

Related session is:

- **WWDC 2010 Session 141**, “*Crafting Custom Cocoa Views*”

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TreeView/Introduction/Intro.html